# Start a long time background task

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

User request some page at my website.

What i want to do? Send to user a fast answer and start background task which take a long time.
It looks like:

```
public ActionResult index()
{
    var task = new Task(Stuff);

    //start task async
    task.start(); 

    return View();
}

public void Stuff()
{
    //long time operation    
}
```

How can i do it?

Comment: How can do what? You already have the code, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can pass the Task StartNew() method a parameter that indicates the task you're starting is "long running", which provides a hint to the Task Scheduler to start the task on a new thread.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Stuff, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978607.aspx#diforwc-ap02_plag_howtomultithread

While you need it for ASP.NET MVC, you can use the core idea of this ASP.NET WebForms example.

The approach is create a worker thread to do your job, start it and send a "waiting" page to the user. This "waiting" page will refresh at every N seconds, looking for the results processed by the worker thread. When it finishes, the "waiting" page shows the results.

Answer (score 0):

you want to define a delegate and fire it off before returning. See, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301332.aspx