# Background task in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, multitasking

```
public JsonResult GetScore(int StudentID = 0)
{
    //fetch the score for the user
    //--Call sendReport
    //return the score to the calling method
}

public void SendReport(int StudentID = 0)
{
    //Logic to get the detaied marks and prepare the report's PDF
    //Mail the generated PDF back to student
}
```

In my web application, while Student clicks for score student will get his/her score on screen and will get detailed report's PDF mailed to his/her registered mail.

Now problem is I would like to run SendReport in background, so student will come to know his/her score immediately without waiting.

I've gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684112/start-a-long-time-background-task) but it gives me error of invalid argument.

Comment: Can you post the specific exception and maybe the stack trace?

Comment: Make sure you have read the following blog post before even starting with the implementation of this task: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx Because after reading it, you might realize that what you are trying to achieve is not a good design at all. I am mentioning this just in case you waste too much of a time right now in implementations and regret it later when you release your application into the wild.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks Darin, any other solution for speeding up the application in the same scenario ?

Comment: You could delegate the PDF report generation and the email sending to a separate, dedicated Windows Service. Or to a standard console application that will be scheduled to run at regular intervals (using Windows Scheduler for example), it will query your database for all users that have requested scores (I guess you have this information, right?), generate the report and send an email. All this will happen in a separate and specifically dedicated application for this task. This should not happen inside your ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Good Suggestion Darin, any way how can I make SendReport method threadsafe for a while?

Comment: What issues related to thread safety are you currently encountering?

Comment: I haven't developed full application yet, I am asking if thread1 is using SendReport(), than how to make sure that other thread don't have access to SendReport() until it gets released by thread1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just call it in a new thread

```
new Thread(SendReport(StudentID)).Start();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public JsonResult GetScore(int StudentID)
{
    //fetch the score for the user
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendReport(StudentID));
    //return the score
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a quick and dirty solution to this problem, it's to make your controller look like this:

```
public JsonResult GetScore(int StudentID = 0)
{
    //fetch the score for the user
    //return the score to the calling method
}

public JsonResult SendReport(int StudentID = 0)
{
    //Logic to get the detaied marks and prepare the report's PDF
    //Mail the generated PDF back to student
    //Return a JsonResult indicating success
}
```

... and then make **two** JQuery calls to your controller.  One to get the score and one to kick off the report.  You can display the score as soon as you get it, and the report will still be chugging in the background.

Bear in mind, if the report takes longer than a few seconds to generate and email, you really should consider moving that execution to a service that you simply *activate* via MVC, since running it in a controller method ties up web server resources until it's finished.

See the new [MVC async documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) for details on doing this.